# 403 Forbidden Error when deploying app through nginx in docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my frontend through nginx in a docker container. The URL should be http://10.122.45.116/sub.

I keep on getting 403 Forbidden Error. The file is existing. The permissions of both /home directory and index_.html file is 777. I suppose port 80 should be open by default.

Here is the content of /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.122.45.116;
    location /sub {
        root /home;
        index index_.html;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:5000;
    }
 }
```

Here is the content of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  #gzip  on;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here is the code of supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
# Graceful stop, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
stopsignal=QUIT
```

I've looked at various answers but none of them seemed to help me.
Please help!

Comment: What does the nginx error log show?

Comment: no errors. it's blank.
When i do sudo nginx -t, everything seems to be ok:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Please show us your docker-compose/dockerfile

Comment: actually the docker image is created by another team. they just gave us a container where we're supposed to deploy the app. we do have root access to container but i;m not really sure how i can access the files you asked for by through the root user. could you help?

Comment: What is the command you are using to run the container?

Comment: after ssh-ing into the container, i execute "sudo docker exec -it nginx_dashboard bash" to get into root. To start nginx, i use "service start nginx". Actually nginx is also added in supervisord.conf (will edit the question to include the code). but i have killed the PIDs of nginx processes before trying to restart nginx.

Comment: `docker exec` is used to execute a command on a *running* container. How are you running it? What is the `docker run` command you are using?

Comment: there is another team that created and ran the container. i am just trying to deploy the app in the running container. are there any specifics needed in the command? if so, what are those? so that i can ask the team about those stuff

Comment: It appears that your container is configured to write the error to stderr instead of a file. Run `docker logs --tail 200 nginx_dashboard` after getting the 403 again. Please update your question with the output.

Comment: interestingly, i don;t see any logs in relation to nginx. i tried doing "service nginx restart" several times but i don;t see any logs in relation to that. all the logs i see are in relation to my backend. so whenever i try to fetch backend data, i do see logs appearing but when i try to restart nginx and access the frontend through 10.122.45.116/sub, no logs appearing and the site still shows 403 error. what could that mean?

Answer (score -2):

***10.122.45.11***  **this ip is Private IP**

what is your public ip address and try with public ip

[What is the difference between a Public IP address and a Private IP address?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-Public-IP-address-and-a-Private-IP-address)

Comment: i don't get why i need to use public instead of private. since this is a proprietary web app, it could only be accessed within organization network which is ok. i don;t get the relevance of using public ip address to fix deployment issue in nginx. in addition, i saw this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-it-possible-to-use-private-ip-address-instead-of-domain-for-nginx-load-balancer-setup

Comment: as mentioned in the question, the permissions of both the /home dir and index_.html file are 777.